# Circumsphere of a tetrahedron undefined?

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation

I am trying to find 3D alpha shapes from my data-set. In doing so, I am keeping only those tetrahedra that have circumradius below a certain threshold. However, while finding the circumradius of the tetrahedra making up the delaunay triangulation of the data, I am finding that for some cases, it becomes imaginary. I am using the standard formulae, given for example, in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumsphere.html.
Are these formualae always valid for any (non-degenerate) tetrahedron ?
An example of the vertices of a tetrahedra for which it fails:

1.0e+03 *

-0.882361572000000   1.832846680000000   8.039920898000000

-0.871205933000000   2.190948975000000   7.713502440999999

-0.874571533000000   1.637495972000000   7.953884766000000

-0.945120239000000   1.753712891000000   8.093748535000000

I am using Matlab here, along with its delaunayn function. Essentially in the formula
$r = \frac{ \sqrt{D_x^2 + D_y^2 + D_z^2 - 4 a c} }{2 |a| }$, the discriminant under the square root becomes negative. My computed values are:

[$D_x \, D_y \, D_z \, a \, c$] =

1.0e+14 *

0.000152327124454

0.000160507051388

-0.000890797019744

-0.000000057932589

-3.705507881061755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) they would say "show me your code." It looks like you've at least done something with the minus sign in calculating `Dy`. Here's my code where the four vertices of the tetrahedron are stored in the 4-by-3 matrix `xyz`:

```
w = ones(4,1);
s = sum(xyz.^2,2);
Dx = det([s xyz(:,2:3) w])
Dy = -det([s xyz(:,[1 3]) w])
Dz = det([s xyz(:,1:2) w])
a = det([xyz w])
c = det([s xyz])
r = 0.5*sqrt(Dx^2+Dy^2+Dz^2-4*a*c)/abs(c)
```

The resulting radius is a positive real value: about 8.72e-6. Yes, the negative `Dy` goes away when it gets squared (and could be omitted in your case) – did you maybe put the negative inside of the square root?

I can't answer your your more mathematical question, but I'd hazard to guess that this formula is fine. I'd think that numerical issues would potentially be a bigger issue. There's potential for overflow in your case if the numbers get bigger.

Comment: You are right. I had a bug in the Dy matrix. Thanks for your help. The formula should be valid for any tetrahedron with non-zero volume (i.e., 4 vertices are not coplanar or equivalently no 3 vertices are collinear).

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the radius should be:

$r = 0.5\times\sqrt{Dx^2+Dy^2+Dz^2-4ac}/|a|\approx 0.5577$

But thanks, you helped me a lot.